# How do I get the equation number on the same line as the equation?

Tags: equations, number

My equation number ends up on a new line. I am writing in Tufte class.

This is example code:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    &p_{u} &&\leftarrow p_{u}\cdot \frac{\Sigma_{i\in I_{u}}q_{i}\cdot $r_{ui}$}{\Sigma_{i\in I_{u}}\cdot q_{i} \cdot \hat{r}_{ui}+\lambda_{u}\lvert I_{u}\rvert p_{u}} 
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: *A priori*, this is due to the equation being too long for the text width of the class.

Comment: why use alignat if you only have one line? If you just used `equation` it might fit, except you have given no information about the page size or font size so it is impossible to guess. Please always make examples complete small documents that show the problem.

Comment: also is that `\Sigma` really a sigma or should it be `\sum` ?

Comment: What are the `$` signs doing in an environment that's already defined as math?  They should be accompanied by error messages in your log.

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors and inappropriate use of `\Sigma` instead of `\sum`. And please tell us which document class you employ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `article` documentclass and writing equation on usula way (removed all `\cdot`s) and removing superfluous `alignedat` environment I got the following result

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    p_{u} \gets p_{u} 
        \frac{\sum_{i\in I_{u}}q_{i} r_{ui}}
              {\sum_{i\in I_{u}} q_{i} \hat{r}_{ui} + \lambda_{u}\abs{I_{u}} p_{u}}
\end{equation}
or maybe
\begin{equation}
    p_{u} \gets p_{u}
        \frac{\sum\limits_{i\in I_{u}}q_{i} r_{ui}}
             {\sum\limits_{i\in I_{u}} q_{i} \hat{r}_{ui} + \lambda_{u}\abs{I_{u}} p_{u}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```